# FindWindow is not working?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, findwindow

I just want to know why this code is not working?

```
    HWND hWnds = FindWindow(NULL,(LPCTSTR)"Calculator");
```

It always returns NULL for the hWnds....

Any idea how to fix this? Thank you :)

Comment: Don't cast, use L"Calculator".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont cast the string.

```
HWND hWnds = FindWindow(NULL,_T("Calculator"));
```

Comment: I've tried above code, I wonder why I keep getting this error?  1>c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\invoke\invoke\invoke.cpp(59) : error C3861: '_T': identifier not found

Comment: do you have `#include <windows.h>` at the top?

Comment: @zia: `_T` is actually defined in <tchar.h>

Answer (score 0):

Make a folder named 'Calculator' and enter into it using Windows Explorer.

Now run your program - wrong window handle would be returned!

Using Spy++ on Windows 7, I found out **class-name** of Calculator window to be: **CalcFrame**.

Try using this:

```
HWND hWnds = FindWindow(_T("CalcFrame"), NULL);
```